# Linking a google form and fusion table with live updates, without submitting the form

Tags: google-docs, google-fusion-tables

I want to link together a fusion table with a form.  I will use this for students in a class to indicate when they have completed different exercises.  I have read this page:
http://kh-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/code/instructions.html
which indicates that it is possible to link forms and a fusion table.

The twist that I would like the students to be able to update their answers on the page without having to hit submit, so they can easily go back and change things as they work. If they have to click submit then they will lose their place which is not what I want.

Any way to do submit the form data as they answer the question, without having to hit submit?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's going to work with Google Forms and the sync to Fusion Tables.

Something else to look into: 
Create a view on a Fusion Table for each student. They can edit their own table to add /edit rows. You can see their answers all aggregated together in the base table.

Here's an article describing how to do that: 
http://support.google.com/fusiontables/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2584135

Within the table, they will have a simpler form-like interface for editing the data in a given row.  You can check this out yourself in a table you own by going into Experimental, then select a row, and click the pencil icon to edit it.

Hope that provides a useful alternative,

-Rebecca